# Determine dimensions of full-screen macOS application windows below the camera housing notch

Tags: swift, macos

I need to determine the dimensions of a full-screen application window on a display with a camera housing notch. I'm using a Mac Book Pro (14-inch, 2021) but I'm looking for a general technique. Crucially, I need to do this from outside the full-screen application itself before it is launched, so I can predict the window position in advance in an application testing/screen-capture scenario.

The full screen size including the notch region is reported from [`NSScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen) [`frame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388387-frame) as 1512x982. The [`safeAreaInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3882821-safeareainsets) are reported as `top = 32.0` with the other three edges being zero. Subtracting the top inset gives a size of 1512x950, yet full-screen applications (I'm using Chromium) report a maximised window size of 1512x945, which is what we might expect as it has a 16:10 aspect ratio. For example, [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com) allows setting the resolution to 1512x945 HiDPI 16:10 to ignore the notch area.

The regions returned by [auxiliaryTopLeftArea](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3882915-auxiliarytopleftarea) and [auxiliaryTopRightArea](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3882916-auxiliarytoprightarea) also have a height of 32.

Confusingly, [`visibleFrame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388369-visibleframe) reports 1512x944 (not 945) and I'm not sure where the one pixel discrepancy is coming from.

What API calls can I make to determine the dimensions of the full-screen application area?